# Why does WWW::Mechanize and login-data break when I switch from a query string to a hash?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

The following script works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $loginData = "userName=username&password=password&deeplinkForward=%2Fselfcare%2Frestricted%2FprepareCoCo.do&x=84&y=7";
my $loginUrl = "https://www.login.login/login.do";
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( show_progress => 1 );

my $req = $mech->post( $loginUrl, 'Content' => $loginData  );

my $content = $req->content();
print Dumper $content;
```

But when I replace the line

```
my $req = $mech->post( $loginUrl, 'Content' => $loginData  );
```

with

```
my %hash = (    
    'username' => 'username', 
    'password' => 'password', 
    'deeplinkForward' => '%2Fselfcare%2Frestricted%2FprepareCoCo.do', 
    'x' => '84', 
    'y' => '7' 
);

my $req = $mech->post( $loginUrl, 'Content' => \%hash );
```

it doesn't work any more ( the script works, but the login doesn't ). Is there something worng?

Comment: The return value from `post` is a response, not a request, so it's more common to use `$res` or `$rsp` rather than `$req`.  That's not the cause of your problem, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to unescape `deeplinkForward`:

```
'deeplinkForward' => '/selfcare/restricted/prepareCoCo.do',
```

Otherwise, WWW::Mechanize thinks you want to send literal % signs, and helpfully escapes them for you.

To see what's going wrong, try adding this code right before the `$mech->post` line:

```
use HTTP::Request::Common 'POST';
print POST( $loginUrl, 'Content' => $loginData )->as_string;
print POST( $loginUrl, 'Content' => \%hash )->as_string;
```

They should be the same, except for the order of the fields.

It's conceivable that the server requires the fields to be listed in that order (it shouldn't, but...).  In that case, you can use an array instead of a hash (hashes don't preserve ordering).  Just replace `%hash` with `@fields` everywhere it appears.

```
print POST( $loginUrl, 'Content' => \@fields )->as_string;
```

Comment: Do username or password contain any % characters?  You'd have to unescape them too.

Comment: Thx, it was the key  “username”  which was wrong – it  should be “userName”.

Comment: Yep, I missed the userName bug.  I compared the two outputs in my editor, but I had case-insensitive search turned on.  At any rate, `$mech->post` just passes its parameters to `HTTP::Request::Common::POST`, which makes that useful to see how it's building your requests.

Comment: The userName bug was the second error; as you explained, the first error was using "%2F" instead of "/".

Answer (score 0):

i don't have mechanize in place, but you can try this and see how it goes

```
my $req = $mech->post( $loginUrl, \%hash);
```